# How to loop over a list of items of a table in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, cursor

i am new in sql and i want that , i have a table  `Customer`
 in which i added a new field `Region` now i want to do some
 alteration in SQL . I want to get all records `Customer`and check on each

```
 // This check will perfome for every customer let suppose we have our first customer
if currentcustomer.Country = 'US' 
 {
  UPDATE currentcustomer SET currentcustomer.Region=currentcustomer.id
 }
 else
 {
    UPDATE  currentcustomer SET currentcustomer.Region=currentcustomer.ZIP
  }
```

this is what i want to do but i dont know that how to do this over all customers and how to do this in sql . Please Help me Thanks!!!

Comment: Your edit makes little sense - I'd expect `id` and `ZIP` to be of different, incompatible data types. Can you confirm what you need, exactly?

Comment: let suppose its `Name` and  `FName`

Comment: When posting examples, please try to make them [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable)](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Ok , Good link for Examples . Thanks @Oded

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
UPDATE Customer SET Region='AA'
WHERE Country = 'US'

UPDATE Customer SET Region='ZZ'
WHERE Country <> 'US'
```

Avoid looping within SQL - it is not designed for looping.

Try to formulate your requirements in set based terminology (I need to update all customers who's country is `US` to have region `AA` and all others to region `ZZ`).

Update:

Seeing your edit, and assuming it is sensible (compatible data types and meaningful data):

```
UPDATE Customer SET Region= id
WHERE Country = 'US'

UPDATE Customer SET Region= Zip
WHERE Country <> 'US'
```

Comment: @Ahsan - All records that have a country `US` or not `US`.

Comment: +1 beat me to it, only I was going to use `<>` instead of `!=`, think they're completely the same anyway?

Comment: @mattytommo - They are in SQL server, though `!=` is not in the ISO standard.

Comment: Or a single `update customer set region = case country when 'us' then 'aa' else 'zz' end`

Comment: @Ahsan - What I wrote will update all `Customer` records according to the `WHERE` criteria.

Comment: I blogged about `<>` vs `!=` a few years ago - https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/03/20/which-to-use-or.aspx